# opencv_createsamples parameters: -bgcolor and -bgthresh

Tags: opencv

Can somebody tell me how to specify the -bgcolor and -bgthresh values? -bgcolor is supposed to specify the background color, but according to the docs I found, it's a single number, no RGB or similar.

[OpenCV Doc - Cascade Classifier Training](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html) says the following:
`Background color (currently grayscale images are assumed);`

Is it a greyscale intensity? Is 0 black or white?

Thanks a lot!

Similar question here, but it explains parameter meaning and not parameter format: [Transparent background for training OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24654124/transparent-background-for-training-opencv)

Comment: for me, grayscale worked (0 = black): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125138/opencv-how-to-create-vec-file-to-use-with-opencv-traincascade/35130506#35130506

Comment: @Micka thanks a lot, this looks like it will help. We unfortunately have raw footage where we cannot cut out the positives so nicely (aerial photography of cows on grasland). But I pick up that 0 the parameter runs from 0 = black to 255 = white - that's what I needed to know. Thanks!

Comment: interesting project =)